# c++ preprocessor macro errors

Tags: c++, macros

Decided to make the life easier I wrote following macros to simplify logger invocation:

```
#define LOG(level_, message_) \
    InfraLogger::instance()->log(level_, \
    boost::filesystem::path(__FILE__).filename().string(), \
    __FUNCTION__, static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream().flush() << message_).str(), __LINE__ )

#define LOG_DEBUG (message_) \
    InfraLogger::instance()->log(log_debug, \
    boost::filesystem::path(__FILE__).filename().string(), \
    __FUNCTION__, static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << message_).str(), __LINE__ )
```

As you can see the only difference is in omitting `level_` argument in `LOG_DEBUG` macro, putting the explicit enumeration value instead.
Invocation is as follows:

```
LOG(log_info, "This is" << "Test message");
LOG_DEBUG("This is" << "Test message");
```

But. While the former compiles and works perfectly, the latter gives the following set of errors:

[image]

I'm totally stuck with this one (tried googling but not reaaly sure what to google for). Hope someone will shed some light.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Lose the space between `LOG_DEBUG` and `(message_)`.

Comment: Aaaaa! Cant believe I'm that dumb! :/ While dealing with trailing spaces, just left those in the middle. Thanks!